# how to find out radius of convergence of the following series?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Consider its taylor series expansion about a point $a$ in $\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$. what is the radius of convergence of this series?

one way is to find out all the derivatives and put in general form of taylor expansion. but that will be lengthy. is there any other method to solve these?

Comment: answer for above question is $(1+a^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac1{1+x^2}$
has poles at
$x = \pm i$.

Therefore,
the radius of convergence
is the distance from
$a$ to the closest
of these poles.

Comment: @ marty cohen awesome